# Placing div vertical middle with parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to place a child element vertically with the parent element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Jajal</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  #body {
   font-family: sans-serif, arial, 'Roboto';
  }
  #outer {
   width: 280px;
   background-color: white;
   height: 253px;
   background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }
  .imgbox {
   height: 174px;
   width: 270px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: black;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .img_content {
   max-height: 174px;
   max-width: 270px;
   margin: 0 auto; 
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: table-cell;
  }
  .titlebox {
   max-width: 270px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .title {
   font-weight: 900;
   font-size: 14px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="outer">
  <div class="imgbox">
   <img class="img_content" src="http://lorempixel.com/700/100" alt="coba">
  </div>
  <div class="titlebox">
   <p class="title">Lorem ipsum Amet</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the img_content class doesn't place verticaly middle with imgbox class when the image is to width?

Comment: Wrap the `img` tag in a `div` and give it `table-cell`. Img is a inline element hence it wont work.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean, but if you want to use `display: table`, the `#outer` div should be the table and the `.imgbox` should be the table-cell with `vertical-align: middle`..

Answer (score 1):

Add following CSS:

```
.imgbox {
   height: 174px;
   width: 270px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: black;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
 } 

.img_content {
   max-height: 174px;
   max-width: 270px;
   position: absolute;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use css3 [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Following css should be added on parent element.

```
.parent {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
#body {
  font-family: sans-serif, arial, 'Roboto';
}
#outer {
  width: 280px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 253px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.imgbox {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 174px;
  width: 270px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
.img_content {
  max-height: 174px;
  max-width: 270px;
}
.titlebox {
  max-width: 270px;
  text-align: center;
}
.title {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="imgbox">
    <img class="img_content" src="http://lorempixel.com/700/100" alt="coba">
  </div>
  <div class="titlebox">
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum Amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lo of ways you could do this. You could wrap he img tag in a div with class of say, wrapper. then the wrapper div would have styling like so :

```
.wrapper {
       vertical-align: middle;
       display: table-cell;
}
```

, and remove the display:table-cell, and vertical-align:middle from the image

Working fiddle using another way if you dont wan any changes in the existing CSS
https://jsfiddle.net/mfkxq728/

Also,you could use either of flex(Browser support might be a concern) or the good old relative-absolute position with a translate-Y. The translate-Y would however need browser prefixes for consistent performance.

Cheers !!